# Remove negative values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a certain query that obtains derived values

```
select datediff(minute, date_field_1, date_field_2) as date_diff from table_name;
```

The problem is that some of the values in the result can be negative as `date_field_1` can be greater than `date_field_2` in some cases.

So this results in negative, along with positive values in the resultant table.

Is there anyway to put some default values or omit and give null or zero in those negative calculated values ?

Using redshift.

Comment: Did one of our solutions solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to catch negative values would be to use `CASE WHEN`. It checks whether your datediff is smaller than 0.
I proposed `0` as default value:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN datediff(minute, date_field_1, date_field_2) < 0 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE datediff(minute, date_field_1, date_field_2) END as date_diff
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when date_field_1 >= date_field_2
             then datediff(minute, date_field_1, date_field_2)
             else 0
        end) as date_diff
from table_name;
```